# Cannot resolve symbol DataContext or Table/column and System.Data.Linq in Visual Studio while developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, sql, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Im working a school project making a windows phone app. The target is 8.1, im following a msdn template whose target is 8.0 to connect to the phones inner sql db.

my c#:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Linq;
namespace No_More_Ramen.Data
{
    public class RecipeDataContext : DataContext
    {
        public RecipeDataContext(string connection) : base(connection)
        {

        }

        public Table<Recipe> Recipes;

        [Table]
        public class Recipe : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private int _recipeId;
            [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert))]
            public int ToDoItemId
            {
                get { return _recipeId; }
                set
                {
                    if (_recipeId != value)
                    {
                        _recipeId = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("RecipeId");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

msdn c#

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace LocalDatabaseSample.Model
{

    public class ToDoDataContext : DataContext
    {
        // Pass the connection string to the base class.
        public ToDoDataContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        { }

        // Specify a table for the to-do items.
        public Table<ToDoItem> Items;

        // Specify a table for the categories.
        public Table<ToDoCategory> Categories;
    }

    [Table]
    public class ToDoItem : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    {

        // Define ID: private field, public property, and database column.
        private int _toDoItemId;

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int ToDoItemId
        {
            get { return _toDoItemId; }
            set
            {
                if (_toDoItemId != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("ToDoItemId");
                    _toDoItemId = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("ToDoItemId");
                }
            }
        }
```

Besides a few name changes the syntax is basically the same, except i can't figure out why Resharper/Compiler is complaining. My thought is because my target is 8.1 not 8 and if that is the case is there a way in Visual Studio to set my target to 8.0?

Comment: What is the the error message that you are getting?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol DataContext.. System.data.linq can be remove...cannot resolve [Table]... @Phaeze

Comment: Go ahead and edit that into your question using the edit link right below the tags.